# Dealing with Meteor.Error and .wrapAsync() - best methods?

Tags: meteor

Please critique the following methods of dealing with errors in Meteor:

A common problem with the `Meteor.wrapAsync()` method on Meteor is that it doesn't seem to return the actual error from the external API:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2774

**1. Example using wrapAsync()**

I'm using a simple API that takes a US zipcode and returns the location information:

*/server/methods.js*

```
var getLocationAsync = function(zipcode, callback){

  HTTP.call("GET", "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/" + zipcode, function(error, result) {
    callback(error,result);
  });

};

var getLocationWithWrap = Meteor.wrapAsync(getLocationAsync);

Meteor.methods({
    getLocationWithWrap: function(zipcode){
        return getLocationWithWrap(zipcode);
    }
});
```

If you do

```
Meteor.call("getLocationWithWrap", "94043", function(error, result){
    if(error){
        console.log("here is the error: ", error)
    } else {
        console.log("success: ", result);
    }
})
```

You get a proper response. But if you pass in an invalid zipcode:

```
Meteor.call("getLocationWithWrap", "940", function(error, result){
    if(error){
        console.log("here is the error: ", error)
    } else {
        console.log("success: ", result);
    }
})
```

You get just a generic `Internal server error [500]` which is meaningless.

**2. Example using try/catch (see code comments)**

```
Meteor.methods({
    getLocationWithWrapTryCatch: function(zipcode){
        try {
          return getLocationWithWrap(zipcode);
        } catch(error){
          // the error object just contains a 'stack' key 
          // and the value is difficult to use
          // but the error is a 404 rather than a 500
          throw new Meteor.Error(error.stack);
        }
    }
});
```

Doing:

```
Meteor.call("getLocationWithWrapTryCatch", "940", function(error, result){
    if(error){
        console.log("here is the error: ", error)
    } else {
        console.log("success: ", result);
    }
})
```

results in an error object that's difficult to parse.

**3. Example using @faceyspacey code**

User @faceyspacey wrote a function that he called `makeAsync` (I've changed the name to `makeSync` since his code is taking an async function and allowing you to write in a synchronous style).

What it does is return an object:

```
{error:  error, data: data}
```

The value of `error` is the actual error returned by the external API. If the value of `error` is `null`, the value of `data` will be the data returned by the external API.

`/server/methods.js`

```
Meteor.makeSync = function(fn, context) {
  return function (/* arguments */) {
    var self = context || this;
    var newArgs = _.toArray(arguments);
    var callback;

    for (var i = newArgs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      var arg = newArgs[i];
      var type = typeof arg;
      if (type !== "undefined") {
        if (type === "function") {
          callback = arg;
        }
        break;
      }
    }

    if(!callback) {
      var fut = new Future();
            callback = function(error, data) {
               fut.return({error:  error, data: data});
            };

      ++i; 
    }

    newArgs[i] = Meteor.bindEnvironment(callback);
    var result = fn.apply(self, newArgs);
    return fut ? fut.wait() : result;
  };
};

var getLocationAsync = function(zipcode, callback){

  HTTP.call("GET", "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/" + zipcode, function(error, result) {
    callback(error,result);
  });

};

var getLocationWithMakeSync = Meteor.makeSync(getLocationAsync);

Meteor.methods({
    getLocationWithMakeSync: function(zipcode){
        var result = getLocationWithMakeSync(zipcode);
        if( result.error === null ){
            return result.data;
        } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error(result.error.response.statusCode, "Zipcode cannot be found.");
        }
    },
});
```

Now when you do

```
Meteor.call("getLocationWithWrap", "94043", function(error, result){
    if(error){
        console.log("here is the error: ", error)
    } else {
        console.log("success: ", result);
    }
});
```

You get the actual error returned from the external API or the error-less result.

I personally like the third method much better because you have the actual error object to play with from the external API. Am I missing anything here? Are there better ways of handling async errors when using external APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@faceyspacey's way of doing it is the best way in my opinion. If you look at the source code for wrapAsync, it's very similar (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/meteor/helpers.js#L90). The method is also used in several external packages.

Comment: Would you happen to know what the future is for @faceyspacey's way? Will it be rolled into Meteor core or as a package? Right now I'm hacking my own Stripe-API-Sync methods using his code. All the other packages for making Stripe synchronous use `wrapAsync`

Comment: The future is required from "var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
3", a NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers. It is well used within the Meteor core libraries.

Comment: Oh, haha, sorry, I meant "do you know what the future holds" for faceyspacey's way. I'm not talking about future/fibers.

Comment: The future holds basically the same thing as the default Meteor implementation's future: a callback to be called once the function call finishes. The difference is faceyspacey wraps the callback() with the "correct" error/data arguments so that the error will be correctly positioned in the arguments

Answer (score 1):

I came here having the same trouble you were: the error being thrown contains a stack trace and not the original error.  It turns out that the original error is used as the prototype of the object containing the stack trace, however:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2774#issuecomment-70710564

> ... all the expected properties are there, but they're on the
>   prototype of the error object instead of on the object itself. To see
>   this, add `for (var key in e) { console.log(e, e[key]); }` in the catch
>   block.

I tested it and, sure enough, it works.

Comment: Why. Why is it like this.

/facepalm

Comment: It makes sense to me in retrospect.  Its kind of an elegant way of attaching a stack trace to the object without actually changing the object.  I'm a bit new to Javascript and its inheritance model, though, so it wasn't a pattern I was familiar with.  And it didn't help that inherited properties don't show up with `console.log(e)`.