# What payment service do you recommend to use with MeteorJS?

Tags: meteor

I'm looking for something, preferably, that has a nice API integration with Meteor. I need something simple where I can just "send" the amount and then get a confirmation that the payment has been completed.

Any suggestions, in terms of good customer support are also appreciated.

Thank you!

PS: Stripe looks interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also recommend Stripe. Here's a package that I created that borrows heavily from @copleykj's lovely package:

https://atmospherejs.com/hpp/stripe-makesync

The package is up to date since it gets the server methods directly from the latest Stripe npm package and client methods from Stripe itself.

There was one thing that I thought could have been improved in `copleykj:stripe-sync`. It uses Meteor's `wrapAsync` method which does not return good errors and I personally don't like coding in a `try/catch` style:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2774

Here's my second package that "fixes" this issue:

https://atmospherejs.com/hpp/makesync

As far as I know, all the other Stripe packages don't return proper Stripe errors either, which is extremely important for something like Stripe since errors happen frequently and you must know what kind of error Stripe is returning to you so you can deal with it.

EDIT:

You can check out my other post about Meteor error handling:

[Dealing with Meteor.Error and .wrapAsync() - best methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282493/dealing-with-meteor-error-and-wrapasync-best-methods/31282613#31282613)

Comment: Why do you answer such an off-topic question? It's extremely opinion-based **AND** asking for an external resource!

Comment: @Kyll 

Because I don't mind this one. How about you move this question over to SoftwareRecs and provide an answer of your own? I also don't have the time or inclination to monitor two different StackExchange sites, especially one that has only 6 Meteor-related questions in the entire history of it's **existence** - http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=meteor - It's a waste of time for me and a **guaranteed** waste of time for anyone posting on there looking for Meteor answers. They won't get anything, not even an opinion. Be real here.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny, thanks for explanation. I'll be trying your package when I start the app in the coming months. And yes, it should be nice to get the original errors from Stripe directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Stripe. They have great analytics, extremely simple pricing and it's really easy to integrate.

Here's what makes Stripe a compelling choice: http://stackshare.io/stripe

---

This package is the best way to integrate Stripe at the moment.

https://atmospherejs.com/copleykj/stripe-sync

```
Stripe = StripeSync(key);

try {
    var account = Stripe.account.retrieve()
} catch(error) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(1001, error.message);
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on why `copleykj:stripe-sync` is "the best" at the moment? `mrgalaxy:stripe` seems to be the most popular, and it's kept up to date.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack: https://github.com/tyler-johnson/stripe-meteor/issues/36

Comment: Oh ok, so `mrgalaxy:stripe` is apparently not kept up to date!

Comment: Why do you answer such an off-topic question? It's extremely opinion-based **AND** asking for an external resource!